# Responsive checkbox is too wide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I am trying to do simple quiz using Rails and Bootstrap, but I have problem with checkboxes being too wide on small screens and it covers label of that checkbox ([image: pic rel].

My view looks like this:

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h2><%= t(:quiz) %></h2>
  <div>
    <%= form_for(:test, url: quiz_path) do |f| %>
      <% @quiz.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
        <div>
          <% if task = Task.find_by(id: task) %>
            <%= image_tag(task.asset, class: "img-responsive") %>
            <%= task.text %>
            <% answers = task.correct_answers + task.wrong_answers %>
            <% answers.shuffle! %>
            <fieldset>
              <!-- Dodać półotwarte -->
              <% answers.each do |answer| %>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <%= f.check_box("task#{index}", {class: "checkbox", multiple: true}, answer, nil)%>
                  <%= f.label "task#{index}", answer %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            </fieldset>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit t(:finish_quiz), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it look normal a.k.a. like desktop version, just bigger (square-like of course)?

Comment: try removing `nil` param in `f.check_box`.

Comment: How is that supposed to fix anything?

Comment: I've faced this issue earlier and it was discovered that `nil` is not a mandatory field. If you the html source code of the the conversion, you should know the reason :)

Comment: Well it doesnt make any difference for me. Still the same.

Comment: Can you please add, how does html source code look like?